# Nesting partial mocks with OCMock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mocking, ocmock

Can one form a partial mock of an object that is already a partial mock of another object, i.e. can one nest partial mocks?

```
// ... outer method

MyClass *myObjectSaved = myObject;

id mockMyObject = MCPartialMock(myObject);
OCMStub([mockMyObject flag]).andReturn(YES);

// ... call to inner method (several other calls in between)
// pass in mockMyObject as myObject
// (it should not have to care whether it receives object or its mock)

    id mockMyObject = MCPartialMock(myObject);
    OCMStub([mockMyObject flag]).andReturn(NO);

    // ... tests inside inner method

    [mockMyObject stopMocking];

    // ... return from inner method

[mockMyObject stopMocking];
```

Prototyping suggests that `stopMocking` in the inner method removes the entire mocking state, i.e. when the inner method returns to the outer method `myObjectSaved` is no longer reported as `OCMockObject(MyClass)` but as `MyClass`.

So can one nest partial mocks with OCMock 3?